# react-hook-form: how to get the select value

Tags: react-select, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-form` with `react-select`. The below is the code

```
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";


const scriptOptions = [
    { value: "imd", label: "Immediate" },
    { value: "sch", label: "Scheduled" },
];

<Controller
    name="resetType"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <CreatableSelect
            {...field}
            options={scriptOptions}
        />
    )}
/>
```

the value of `resetType` looks like

```
resetType: {
    label: "Immediate"
    value: "imd"
}
```

instead I want

```
resetType: "imd"
```

How to get this done

Comment: You can add onChange handle to CreatableSelect. After that, you can modify value of select

Comment: can you show some code for this

Comment: Is this right?

https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-v5fkw?file=/example.tsx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052566/return-the-value-of-react-select-using-react-hook-form-with-typescript?rq=1

Comment: the sandbox does not use react-hook-form